# a C program that reads a sequence of numbers and display a message

Tags: c

The program should have the following guidelines:

1. The numbers are read from the standard input.
2. The first number is the length of the sequence (n) followed by n numbers.(ie, if you put '54321' the length of the sequence is 5 numbers)
3. If n is 0 or negative, the program displays the message “Error_1” followed
   by a new line on the standard input.
4. If the length is shorter than n, it displays “Error_2” followed by a new    line and quits.

I'm finding point number 2 difficult

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int i,j,k;

    printf("Enter a Number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    if (i <= 0 ) {
        printf("Error_1\n");
    } else if(){
        printF("Error_2\n")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int i,j,k;

    printf("Enter a Number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    if (i <= 0 ) {
        printf("Error_1\n");
    } else{

        scanf("%d",&j);
        k=0;

        while(j>0)
        {
            k++;
            j=j/10;
        }

        if(k<i)
            printf("Error_2\n");
    }
}
```

so what i did was, i found out the length of number entered and if the length does not match with provided length , it prints error2. i found out the length by continously dividing the number by 10 till it becomes 0.

Comment: The last if statement doesn't satisfy the requirement. Your code prints `Error_2` if either the length of the sequence is less than the number i or more than the number i. But the program's requirement is that the program must print `Error_2` if the length of the sequence is less than the number i. So just change that statement from 'if(k<i||k>i) to if (k <i)' rest all is fine.

Comment: I did that on purpose, but anyway thnx for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

there is something you have to understand

your code:

```
"if (i <= 0 ) {

    printf("Error_1\n");

} else if () {/* I'm talking about this*/

    printF("Error_2\n")

}"
```

commend: /* its mean else if (its empty!!) you should write condition in the if, what you need to do its just use if and not else or else if
https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-if-else-statement*/
currect code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{

    int num,cnt=0;

    printf("Enter length: "\n);
    scanf("%d", &num);

    while(num > 10) //checking first number
    {
      cnt++;
      num /= 10;
    }

    if(num <= 0)
    {
          printf("Error_01\n");
    }
    if(num == (count + 1)!)
    {
           printf("Error_02");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. You can use log base 10 to compute the length of the sequence. Easier and clener.
To compile the code use -lm flag.See the following command:
`gcc sampleFilename.c -lm`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main() {

    int i,num, length;

    printf("Enter a Number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    if (i <= 0 ) {
        printf("Error_1\n");
    } 
    else{
         printf("Enter the number: ");
         scanf("%d",&num);
         length=(int) log10(num)+1;// compute the length of the number .. read about log10
         if (length < i ) //length of the sequence is less than the number 'i'
             printf("Error_2\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code,

Hope this will work

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,k;


    printf("Enter any number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    k = 0;

    if(i <= 0)
    {
          printf("Error_01\n");
    }

    printf("Enter value number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &j);


    while(j != 0) // check till first digit
    {

        k++;

        j /= 10;
    }


    if(k != i)
    {
           printf("Error_02\n");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

by the way this was referred from 
https://codeforwin.org/2016/10/c-program-to-count-number-of-digits-in-number.html